# why my python read makes so many new lines?

Tags: python

I want to do the following, I want to read a txt file line by line and then print the input to the console, So i have the following `input.txt`:

```
1
2
3
```

and the python code looks like this:

```
file = open("input.txt")

for line in file:
    print line
```

why I get a output like:

```
1

2

3
```

and not:

```
1
2
3
```

how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for line in file:
    print line
```

`print` prints some text and then also prints a `'\n'` new line after it. You can use a trailing comma to stop this:

```
for line in file:
    print line,
```

Or just `.rstrip()` it:

```
for line in file:
    print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `print` function in Python3 lets you suppress the line ending. In Python2.6+ you can import the print function from the `__future__` module

```
from __future__ import print_function # required for Python2
file = open("input.txt")

for line in file:
    print(line, end="")
```